# Return true if a binary number either contains all zero or all ones on a single flip.(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, binary

I got a program where any binary number is considered and with 1 flip of either 0 or 1, if we get all 0s or all 1s, then it returns true else it will return false.

For e.g. 110 on 1 flip of element 0 returns 111 and it is printed as true.
111 is a binary number which on one flip, is printed as false.
Any possible solution of how to solve it?

Looking forward to the best possible solutions. Appreciate if the solution is written using Python.

This is what i had actually done.

```
def binary(num, length = 4):
    return format(num, '#0{}b'.format(length + 2)).replace('0b', '')
n = binary(125)
n.count('0')
n.count('1')
if (n.count('0') == 1) or (n.count('1') == 1):
    return true
```

Actually I had no idea of how to flip it.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to determine whether binary representation of given number contains only one "one" or only one "zero"? There is bit trick to find numbers with single bit set:

```
if (x == 0) 
   return false
if (x & (x - 1) == 0
   return true
```

Explanation: if number looks like `b00001000`, then decrement gives `b00000111` and binary AND leads to zero result

For checking single-zero numbers just invert them

if there is no `~` operator (binary NOT) in Python, you can invert all bits of number with

```
x_inversion = -(x+1)
```

Comment: Inverting the number isn't as easy as it should be (well not in Python)... used the same trick in my response, obviously having only a single bit set means the number is a factor of 2.

Comment: @AChampion look at my solution. Can I get a detailed solution with a better explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the values from 0 to log(x) where x is your output and xor with 2<sup>x</sup> which is 100000... Then you just check, whether what you got is 0 or 2<sup>x+1</sup>-1. It should work fine.

```
def g(x):
    for i in range(int(log(x)/log(2))):
        if x ^ 2 ** i == 0 or x ^ 2 ** i == 2 ** int(log(x)/log(2) + 1) - 1:
            return True
    return False
```

Another solution is to sort the binary interpretation of the number and check, whether these is only one 1 or only one 0. The lambda function written below does exactly that. Since `bin()` returns binary `0b` followed by the binary interpretation of the number I get rid of it and then, remove all `0` to check whether there only one `1`, the second part checks the opposite.

```
f = lambda x: len(str(bin(x))[2:].replace('0','')) == 1 or len(str(bin(x))[2:].replace('1','')) == 1
```

If x is the binary interpretation of the number, you should use this:

```
f = lambda x: len(x.replace('0','')) == 1 or len(x.replace('1','')) == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the flip can apply to any bit of the number, you can just count the occurrence of 1 or 0.  If either result returns 1, then the answer is true, otherwise the answer is false:

```
def one_flip(i):
    # i should be integer, so convert it to string using bin() and get the result excluding the '0b'
    s = bin(i)[2:]
    return s.count('0') == 1 or s.count('1') == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for laughs - with some bitwise manipulations:

```
>>> def single_flip(n):
...    return any(x and not x & (x - 1) for x in [n, n^2**n.bit_length()-1])])
...
>>> single_flip(0b1110111), single_flip(0b1010111), single_flip(0b0001000)
(True, False, True)
```

This just tests whether the number or its bitwise complement (not 2's complement) are a factor of 2.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution:

Get first digit to check against all the others, convert to stirng, because integer is not iterable

```
first = str(number)[0]
```

Loop over all of them, return True if we go through the loop, false if we find a digit that doesn't match

```
for digit in str(number):
    if digit == first:
        continue
    else:
        return False
return True
```